# right click context menu to select whole row

Tags: vb.net

```
  Private Sub dgvDisplay_CellMouseDown(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles dgvDisplay.CellMouseDown
        'If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        '    If e.RowIndex < 0 Or e.ColumnIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub
        '    dgvDisplay.CurrentCell = dgvDisplay(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)
        '    ' Maybe modify the text on your context menu options here?
        'Else
        '    ContextMenuStrip1.Hide()
        'End If

    End Sub
```

I want to be able to show context menu only when the user clicks on a cell and take the whole row , otherwise do nothing and not show event the context menu option

Comment: Dim qu - From.. Add First on the end. Does qu.Rating = r  not work? Need what is BookModule? Maybe after update you need to call Save or Update? to refresh...

Comment: BookModule is the module where i open the xml file and read it! i save it it do not show here but i do! as i said only the author get updated

Comment: Do you mean, highlight the entire row and *then* show a context menu?

Comment: yes highlight and show the context menu to the user in order to choose his next step to do by functon

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to just set the selection mode:

```
dgvDisplay.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
```

If you don't want than mode and need to do this in your MouseDown event, then try it like this:

```
Private Sub dgvDisplay_CellMouseDown(sender As Object, _
                                     e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) _
                                     Handles dgvDisplay.CellMouseDown
  If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
    Dim cell As DataGridViewCell = dgvDisplay.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex)
    If cell.Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Value.ToString) Then
      dgvDisplay.ClearSelection()
      For i As Integer = 0 To dgvDisplay.Columns.Count - 1
        dgvDisplay.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(i).Selected = True
      Next
      ContextMenuStrip1.Show(dgvDisplay, dgvDisplay.PointToClient(Cursor.Position))
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

In order to select more than one cell, the `MultiSelect` property needs to be set to true.

Comment: it is working but when i right click on the datagridview and there is no cell with information the context menu still shows up..i do not want to be like this! how can i make it word as i want?

Comment: still showing the context menu after i cliked in the space that there is no cells

Comment: @vkaleri Do you have the dgvDisplay.ContextMenuStrip property set?

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: @vkaleri Well, don't do that.

Comment: what not to do?

Comment: @vkaleri `dgvDisplay.ContextMenuStrip = Nothing`